# Where can I find game postmortems with a programmer perspective

Tags: software-engineering, education

There are a number of interesting game post-mortems in places like GDC vault or [gamastura.com](http://www.gamasutra.com/features/postmortem/). The post-mortems are generally give with a CEO/manager perspective or a designer perspective, or, more often a combination of both e.g [DOOM postmortem](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1014627/Classic-Game-Postmortem)

But I have not been able to find many post-mortems which are primarily from the programmers perspective. I'm looking for discussions and rational for technical choices and tradeoffs and how technical problems were overcome. The motivation here is to learn what kind of problems real game programmers encounter and how they go about solving them.

A perfect example of what I'm looking for is Renaud Bédard's excellent GDC talk on the development of Fez, "[Cubes all the way down](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1015731/Cubes-All-the-Way-Down)". Where can I find more like that?

Comment: Hey Ken, unfortunately these types of open ended list generation questions are too broad for the site. There isn't a correct answer to this question. Try a site that is more discussion oriented like Reddit.

Comment: Just generally troll blogs and look for posts and bookmark them. Jonathan Blow's talk is pretty good - ["How to program independent games"](http://the-witness.net/news/2011/06/how-to-program-independent-games/). Also try using social bookmarking results such as [delicious for gamedev,talks](https://delicious.com/search/gamedev,talks/everyone)